# Mongodb findAndModify each document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that contains a number of documents each document contains an array and I want to remove the lowest value from this Array for each document.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this? Is findAndModify capable of performing this type of operation?

Do I need to use forEach?

Comment: There's no set-oriented operation for this, so your best bet is to just iterate over the collection and update each doc's array in turn as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JohnnyHK's comments are right.  The only way to do this is to `find()` all the documents, update them individually, and resave them.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the purpose of the FindAndModify command, like it is stated in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/):

> The findAndModify command atomically modifies and returns a single document.

You should probably use the regular `update` method with the `multi` flag set to true. Check out the [update documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating).

Comment: `multi` only helps if you want to apply the same update to multiple docs.